# Positive lookahead doesn't stop at first occurrence

Tags: ruby, regex

I use the regex

```
(?<=Charset:\s).+(?=<br\/>)
```

on the following data (There is no newline char in the data, I made it look better) to capture the Charset string

```
<div class="box_t">Parameters</div>
<div class="box_c">Charset: i763zLFYKBqVs@nZ8PyO}N9<br/>
Input Base: 23<br/>Solution Base: 19<br/>
Timelimit: 3.1416 seconds<br/></div>
```

However, my match ended up being

```
i763zLFYKBqVs@nZ8PyO}N9<br/>
Input Base: 23<br/>
Solution Base: 19<br/>
Timelimit: 3.1416 seconds
```

It seems that the positive lookahead did not stop after the first occurrence. Is there a way to make it stop?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

An easy way is to use the non-greedy operator: Change `.+` to `.+?`

```
(?<=Charset:\s).+?(?=<br\/>)
```

Comment: arghhh you beated me to the punch

Comment: Ah, didn't know ? can be used in this way : p. Thanks

Comment: @sawa thank you! Could you maybe explain how this is working, I was searching for a similar solution for some time, and I am not sure how this is working, but it does!

Comment: @soey Quantifiers like `*` or `+` try to match as long as possible. Putting `?` after them turns them to try to match as short as possible.